# r-find two closest values in a vector

Tags: r, match

I tried to find two values in the following vector, which are close to 10. The expected value is 10.12099196 and 10.63054170. Your inputs would be appreciated.

```
 [1]  0.98799517  1.09055728  1.20383713  1.32927166  1.46857509  1.62380423  1.79743107  1.99241551  2.21226576  2.46106916  2.74346924  3.06455219  3.42958354  3.84350238  4.31005838
[16]  4.83051356  5.40199462  6.01590035  6.65715769  7.30532785  7.93823621  8.53773241  9.09570538  9.61755743 10.12099196 10.63018180 11.16783243 11.74870531 12.37719092 13.04922392
[31] 13.75661322 14.49087793 15.24414627 16.00601247 16.75709565 17.46236358 18.06882072 18.51050094 18.71908344 18.63563523 18.22123225 17.46709279 16.40246292 15.09417699 13.63404124
[46] 12.11854915 10.63054170  9.22947285  7.95056000  6.80923943  5.80717982  4.93764782  4.18947450  3.54966795  3.00499094  2.54283599  2.15165780  1.82114213  1.54222565  1.30703661
[61]  1.10879707  0.94170986  0.80084308  0.68201911  0.58171175  0.49695298  0.42525021  0.36451350  0.31299262  0.26922281  0.23197860  0.20023468  0.17313291  0.14995459  0.13009730
[76]  0.11305559  0.09840485  0.08578789  0.07490387  0.06549894  0.05735864
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative could be allowing the user to control for the "tolerance" in order to set what "closeness" is, this can be done by using a simple function:

```
close <- function(x, value, tol=NULL){
  if(!is.null(tol)){
    x[abs(x-10) <= tol]
  } else {
    x[order(abs(x-10))]
  }
}
```

Where `x` is a vector of values, `value` is the value of comparison for closeness, and `tol` is logical, if it's `NULL` it returns all the "close" values ordered by "closeness" to `value`, otherwise it returns just the values meeting the condition given in `tol`.

```
> close(x, value=10, tol=.7)
[1]  9.617557 10.120992 10.630182 10.630542


> close(x, value=10)
 [1] 10.12099196  9.61755743 10.63018180 10.63054170  9.22947285  9.09570538 11.16783243
 [8]  8.53773241 11.74870531  7.95056000  7.93823621 12.11854915 12.37719092  7.30532785
[15] 13.04922392  6.80923943  6.65715769 13.63404124 13.75661322  6.01590035  5.80717982
[22] 14.49087793  5.40199462  4.93764782 15.09417699  4.83051356 15.24414627  4.31005838
[29]  4.18947450 16.00601247  3.84350238 16.40246292  3.54966795  3.42958354 16.75709565
[36]  3.06455219  3.00499094  2.74346924  2.54283599 17.46236358 17.46709279  2.46106916
[43]  2.21226576  2.15165780  1.99241551 18.06882072  1.82114213  1.79743107 18.22123225
[50]  1.62380423  1.54222565 18.51050094  1.46857509 18.63563523  1.32927166  1.30703661
[57] 18.71908344  1.20383713  1.10879707  1.09055728  0.98799517  0.94170986  0.80084308
[64]  0.68201911  0.58171175  0.49695298  0.42525021  0.36451350  0.31299262  0.26922281
[71]  0.23197860  0.20023468  0.17313291  0.14995459  0.13009730  0.11305559  0.09840485
[78]  0.08578789  0.07490387  0.06549894  0.05735864
```

In the first example I defined "closeness" to be at most a difference of 0.7 between `value` and each elements in `x`. In the second example the function `close` returns a vector of values where the firsts are the closest to the value given in `value` and the lasts are the farest values from `value`.

Since my solution does not provide an easy (practical) way to find `tol` as @Arun pointed out, one way to find the closest values would be seting `tol=NULL` and asking for the exact number of close values as in:

```
> close(x, value=10)[1:3]
[1] 10.120992  9.617557 10.630182
```

This shows the three values in `x` closest to 10.

Comment: Is there a better way to choose this tolerance? If not, it's not much useful, isn't it? For ex: if the next value closer to 10 is 50...?

Comment: @Arun you're absolutely right, my solution does not give an easy way to find tolerance, but I edited my answer to make it somehow useful.

Comment: +1 - that's what I thought. My benchmarking shows that `order` (I think it uses radix sort?) is slower than `sort`. And I suppose when the data is *really* huge, one could benefit from partial sort even better. Just a remark.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way without using `sort`. However, you can speed it up by using `partial sort`.

```
x[abs(x-10) %in% sort(abs(x-10), partial=1:2)[1:2]]
# [1]  9.617557 10.120992
```

In case the same values are present more than once, you'll get all of them here. So, you can either wrap this with `unique` or you can use `match` instead as follows:

```
x[match(sort(abs(x-10), partial=1:2)[1:2], abs(x-10))]
# [1] 10.120992  9.617557
```

---

#### dput output:

```
dput(x)
c(0.98799517, 1.09055728, 1.20383713, 1.32927166, 1.46857509, 
1.62380423, 1.79743107, 1.99241551, 2.21226576, 2.46106916, 2.74346924, 
3.06455219, 3.42958354, 3.84350238, 4.31005838, 4.83051356, 5.40199462, 
6.01590035, 6.65715769, 7.30532785, 7.93823621, 8.53773241, 9.09570538, 
9.61755743, 10.12099196, 10.6301818, 11.16783243, 11.74870531, 
12.37719092, 13.04922392, 13.75661322, 14.49087793, 15.24414627, 
16.00601247, 16.75709565, 17.46236358, 18.06882072, 18.51050094, 
18.71908344, 18.63563523, 18.22123225, 17.46709279, 16.40246292, 
15.09417699, 13.63404124, 12.11854915, 10.6305417, 9.22947285, 
7.95056, 6.80923943, 5.80717982, 4.93764782, 4.1894745, 3.54966795, 
3.00499094, 2.54283599, 2.1516578, 1.82114213, 1.54222565, 1.30703661, 
1.10879707, 0.94170986, 0.80084308, 0.68201911, 0.58171175, 0.49695298, 
0.42525021, 0.3645135, 0.31299262, 0.26922281, 0.2319786, 0.20023468, 
0.17313291, 0.14995459, 0.1300973, 0.11305559, 0.09840485, 0.08578789, 
0.07490387, 0.06549894, 0.05735864)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your question is clear, so here's another approach.  To find the value closest to your first desired value, `10.12099196` , subtract that from the vector, take the absolute value, and then find the index of the closest element.  Explicit:

```
delx <- abs( 10.12099196 - x)
min.index <- which.min(delx)  #returns index of first minimum if there are duplicates
x[min.index]   #gets you the value itself
```

Apologies if this was not the intent of your question.

Comment: Carl, +1 - the idea's there but it's not quite the complete intent of the OP until you call `which.min` "x" number of times by removing from the vector each time the current min. He needs 2 closest elements to a given value.

Comment: @Arun, thanks.  I was going on the assumption that he wanted to find the best match to each identified value independently.  The answer you and Jilber generated looks pretty good.